# How do I install Server Manager on Windows 8 Professional?

Tags: remote-access, windows-8, windows

I have downloaded and installed [Remote Server Administration Tools for Windows 8](http://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=28972) on my Windows 8 Enterprise machine.

Online resources suggest installing RSAT should also install Server Manager GUI, but I am unable to find it.

Do I need to perform some additional steps to enable Server Manager?

 
I have tried researching this, but haven't come across any solutions.

**Edit:**

[image]

Comment: Have you already gone to "Turn Windows Features on or off" and checked under either Role Administration Tools or Feature Administration Tools?

Comment: @Cole I have neither of those. Does this mean RSAT installation did not complete successfully?

Comment: Hm, that does look a bit funny. I'd try a quick reinstall.

Comment: @Cole Tried reinstalling. Installer reports success, but I think it is actually failing quietly. "Programs and Features" contains no mention of RSAT (I have tried searching by name and KB number).

Comment: It looks like this is an issue with language packs. Download the Windows 8 language pack from the TechNet, copy out the cab file for en-US , change the extension to .mlc and run it. Then, the tools should show up.

Answer (score 5):

I managed to fix this by going to...

- Control Panel > Language
- Click 'Add a Language'
- Select 'English' > 'English (United States)'
- Click 'Download'

Then reinstall the Remote Server Administration Tools.

Not too impressed by the lack of error messages!

Answer (score 3):

After installing the RSAT tools, under Turn Windows Features on or off you should see these options:

[image]

It looks like this is a common issue that has to do with language packs. Download the Windows 8 language pack from the TechNet, copy out the cab file for en-US , change the extension to .mlc and run it. Then, the tools should show up once completed.

[Link to language pack install](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2607607).

Then verify that the language pack is installed by running get-windowspackage -online in a Windows PowerShell (Run As Admin)

Comment: It looks like installer is actually failing quietly. "Programs and Features" contains no mention of RSAT (I have tried searching by name and KB number).

Comment: "Link to language pack" actually points to RSAT download page.

Comment: I can see 1 LanguagePack installed: "Microsoft-Windows-Client-LanguagePack-Package~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~en-GB~6.2.9200"

Comment: You have "en-GB" installed, you need "en-US".

Comment: I could only find a 2GB MultiLanguage pack on MSDN, so I will have to install that later tonight (slow internet connection).

Comment: I was seeing the same thing on W8Pro with en-gb. Installing the en-us language pack and then re-applying the RSAT update fixed it for me. Thanks!